# What's magnitude of the spin of an electron in a superposition state two spin states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin, linear-algebra

An electron is said to have the spin magnitude of -1/2, and this is often called one of the 'intrinsic' properties of an electron.

Does an electron also have a spin magnitude -1/2 when it is in a superposition of two orthogonal spin states, say, $|z+\rangle$ and $|z-\rangle$? Or can we not meaningfully talk about the spin magnitude in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electron has spin - spin magnatude 1/2. When meassured we get spin up or down: -1/2 or 1/2.

Spin is a preserved meaningfull quantity no matter what basis you choose.

QM states are multidimentional, even when messured. And you can always choose a basis so that your state is a superposition or not.